# Javascript Match from Multiple Array Value

Tags: javascript

This is my Array with data:

```
let myvalue= [
    {
        "feeSubHeadId": 1022692502,
        "feeSubHeadName": "Quiz-01",
        "fineAmount": 20
    },
    {
        "feeSubHeadId": 1012182502,
        "feeSubHeadName": "Half Yearly Exam",
        "fineAmount": 0
    },
    {
        "feeSubHeadId": 1022682502,
        "feeSubHeadName": "Quiz-02",
        "fineAmount": 0
    },
    {
        "feeSubHeadId": 1012192502,
        "feeSubHeadName": "Annual Exam",
        "fineAmount": 0
    }
]
```

I want to match array element by another array, for example:

```
let match= [1022692502, 1012182502]
```

In this case expected result is:

```
[
    {
        "fineAmount": 20
    },
    {
        "fineAmount": 0
    }
]
```

How can I do this?

Comment: None of the value in match is matching with `feeSubHeadId` in myvalue

Comment: Sorry, Fixed Now

Answer (score 3):

You should try doing this using [`Array.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) & [`Array.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map). The `Array.filter` will test whether the `feeSubHeadId` is included in the `match`.

Then you can proceed to extract the `fineAmount` property in the `Array.map`.

```js
let myvalue= [
    {
        "feeSubHeadId": 1022692502,
        "feeSubHeadName": "Quiz-01",
        "fineAmount": 20
    },
    {
        "feeSubHeadId": 1012182502,
        "feeSubHeadName": "Half Yearly Exam",
        "fineAmount": 0
    },
    {
        "feeSubHeadId": 1022682502,
        "feeSubHeadName": "Quiz-02",
        "fineAmount": 0
    },
    {
        "feeSubHeadId": 1012192502,
        "feeSubHeadName": "Annual Exam",
        "fineAmount": 0
    }
];
let match= [1022692502, 1012182502];
const matchedItems = myvalue.filter(({feeSubHeadId}) => match.includes(feeSubHeadId)).map(({fineAmount})=> ({fineAmount}));
console.log(matchedItems);
```

We could use [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) also, the first parameter is the filtered array the second one will map it to the new object:

```js
let myvalue= [
    {
        "feeSubHeadId": 1022692502,
        "feeSubHeadName": "Quiz-01",
        "fineAmount": 20
    },
    {
        "feeSubHeadId": 1012182502,
        "feeSubHeadName": "Half Yearly Exam",
        "fineAmount": 0
    },
    {
        "feeSubHeadId": 1022682502,
        "feeSubHeadName": "Quiz-02",
        "fineAmount": 0
    },
    {
        "feeSubHeadId": 1012192502,
        "feeSubHeadName": "Annual Exam",
        "fineAmount": 0
    }
];
let match= [1022692502, 1012182502];
const matchedItems = Array.from(myvalue.filter(({feeSubHeadId}) => match.includes(feeSubHeadId)),
                    ({fineAmount}) => ({fineAmount}));
console.log(matchedItems);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method to filter out required values and then use [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method to format the array element.

```
var res = myvalue
  // filter out elements
  .filter(({ feeSubHeadId }) => match.includes(feeSubHeadId))
  // format array elements
  .map(({ fineAmount }) => ({ fineAmount }));
```

```js
let myvalue= [
    {
        "feeSubHeadId": 1022692502,
        "feeSubHeadName": "Quiz-01",
        "fineAmount": 20
    },
    {
        "feeSubHeadId": 1012182502,
        "feeSubHeadName": "Half Yearly Exam",
        "fineAmount": 0
    },
    {
        "feeSubHeadId": 1022682502,
        "feeSubHeadName": "Quiz-02",
        "fineAmount": 0
    },
    {
        "feeSubHeadId": 1012192502,
        "feeSubHeadName": "Annual Exam",
        "fineAmount": 0
    }
]
let match= [1022692502, 1012182502]


var res = myvalue
  .filter(({ feeSubHeadId }) => match.includes(feeSubHeadId))
  .map(({ fineAmount }) => ({ fineAmount }));
  
console.log(res);
```

Or with [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) method you can combine both.

```
var res = myvalue
  // iterate and push into array if id found
  .reduce((arr, { feeSubHeadId,fineAmount }) => {
    if (match.includes(feeSubHeadId)) arr.push({ fineAmount: fineAmount });
    // return array reference for next iteration
    return arr;
    // set intial value as empty array for result
  }, []);
```

```js
let myvalue= [
    {
        "feeSubHeadId": 1022692502,
        "feeSubHeadName": "Quiz-01",
        "fineAmount": 20
    },
    {
        "feeSubHeadId": 1012182502,
        "feeSubHeadName": "Half Yearly Exam",
        "fineAmount": 0
    },
    {
        "feeSubHeadId": 1022682502,
        "feeSubHeadName": "Quiz-02",
        "fineAmount": 0
    },
    {
        "feeSubHeadId": 1012192502,
        "feeSubHeadName": "Annual Exam",
        "fineAmount": 0
    }
]

let match= [1022692502, 1012182502]


var res = myvalue
  .reduce((arr, { feeSubHeadId,fineAmount }) => {
    if (match.includes(feeSubHeadId)) arr.push({ fineAmount: fineAmount });
    return arr;
  }, []);

console.log(res);
```

For extracting object properties I'd used ES6 [Destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) feature.

Comment: ***On side note*** you can simply do `{fineAmount}` instead of  `{ fineAmount: fineAmount }`

Answer (score 1):

You could use reduce to do this

```js
const res = myvalue.reduce((a, {feeSubHeadId, fineAmount}) => 
    match.includes(feeSubHeadId) ? a.concat({fineAmount}) : a,[]
);
console.log(res);
```

```html
<script>
let myvalue= [
  {
    "feeSubHeadId": 1022692502,
    "feeSubHeadName": "Quiz-01",
    "fineAmount": 20
  },
  {
    "feeSubHeadId": 1012182502,
    "feeSubHeadName": "Half Yearly Exam",
    "fineAmount": 0
  },
  {
    "feeSubHeadId": 1022682502,
    "feeSubHeadName": "Quiz-02",
    "fineAmount": 0
  },
  {
    "feeSubHeadId": 1012192502,
    "feeSubHeadName": "Annual Exam",
    "fineAmount": 0
  }
];
let match= [1022692502, 1022682502];
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use `reduce` and `includes`

```js
let myvalue = [{"feeSubHeadId": 1022692502,"feeSubHeadName": "Quiz-01","fineAmount": 20},{"feeSubHeadId": 1012182502,"feeSubHeadName": "Half Yearly Exam","fineAmount": 0},{"feeSubHeadId": 1022682502,"feeSubHeadName": "Quiz-02","fineAmount": 0},{"feeSubHeadId": 1012192502,"feeSubHeadName": "Annual Exam","fineAmount": 0}]

let match= [1022692502, 1012182502]

let op = myvalue.reduce((op,{feeSubHeadId,fineAmount}) => {
  if(match.includes(feeSubHeadId)){
    op.push({fineAmount})
  }
  return op
},[])

console.log(op)
```